# checksum failed on workstation live fedora 22 64bit download

Tags: fedora, download

I downloaded the iso from https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/

Next, I attempted to follow the instructions at https://getfedora.org/en/verify

I downloaded the checksum file from the following url:

```
getfedora.org/en/static/checksums/Fedora-Workstation-22-x86_64-CHECKSUM
```

I then validated it from the command line:

```
$ gpg --verify-files *-CHECKSUM
gpg: Signature made Fri 22 May 2015 12:47:01 PM PDT using RSA key ID 8E1431D5
gpg: Good signature from "Fedora (22) <fedora@fedoraproject.org>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: C527 EA07 A934 9B58 9C35  E1BF 11AD C094 8E14 31D5
```

Since the RSA key ID matched, I figured the checksum file was good.  Finally, I attempted to match the iso image's checksum with the checksum file:

```
$ sha256sum -c *-CHECKSUM
sha256sum: Fedora-Workstation-netinst-x86_64-22.iso: No such file or directory
Fedora-Workstation-netinst-x86_64-22.iso: FAILED open or read
Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-22-3.iso: FAILED
sha256sum: WARNING: 20 lines are improperly formatted
sha256sum: WARNING: 1 listed file could not be read
sha256sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

The first two sha256sum message lines above are expected, since the ...netinst-x86...iso file doesn't exist in my directory.  Investigating the ...Live... checksum verification failure, I got:

```
$ sha256sum Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-22-3.iso
50f1b411a7be82fc4dee6de6ad66c27280e80567db92a0599a237f3a0647b1f1  
Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-22-3.iso
```

1. Has anyone else gotten the same results that I did?
2. With respect to the checksum file downloaded from the following url

   getfedora.org/en/static/checksums/Fedora-Workstation-22-x86_64-CHECKSUM

what is the significance of the "sha256sum: WARNING: 20 lines are improperly formatted" message?

Answer (score 2):

I think your image is simply actually failing the checksum, either because of a bad mirror, corruption in transit, or local problems. Re-download and try again?

I get

```
$ sha256sum Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-22-3.iso
615abfc89709a46a078dd1d39638019aa66f62b0ff8325334f1af100551bb6cf  Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-22-3.iso
```

exactly as in the official, signed file.

(The 20 invalid lines are the GPG signature; the sha256sum command doesn't know to skip that, and our secure signing system doesn't do detached signatures.)

Comment: Re-executed the download, and re-checked the checksum; it is now good.  This confirms mattdm's hypothesis; my previous download was (for some unknown reason) bad.

Answer (score 0):

I got this warning: `sha256sum: WARNING: 20 lines are improperly formatted` 
because I had empty lines in my file, after removing the empty lines, I was able to fix the warning.